# Regular expression working in Pythex.com but not in pandas

Tags: regex, pandas, python-re, findall

I'm having trouble applying a regex function to a column in a python dataframe. It works fine in Pythex online editor.

Here is the head of my dataframe -

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | UMM SURE THE ADDRESS IS IN 25088 KITTAN DRIVE NORTH CAROLINA 28605 |
| 2 | IT IS ON 26 W STREET 7TH HIGHWAY ORLANDO FLORIDA 28262 |
| 3 | COOL 757979 EAST TYRON BLVD NEW YORK NEW YORK 29875 |

I've tried the following code to create another column which gives us just the address. but the new column is showing up as empty.

```
df['Address']=df['Text'].str.findall('[0-9]{2,6}(?:\s+\S+){3,8}\s{1,}\b(?:FLORIDA|NORTH CAROLINA|NEW YORK)\b')
```

The desired output should look like -

| ID | Text | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UMM SURE THE ADDRESS IS IN 25088 KITTAN DRIVE NORTH CAROLINA 28605 | 25088 KITTAN DRIVE NORTH CAROLINA |
| 2 | IT IS ON 26 W STREET 7TH HIGHWAY ORLANDO FLORIDA 28262 | 26 W STREET 7TH HIGHWAY ORLANDO FLORIDA |
| 3 | COOL 757979 EAST TYRON BLVD NEW YORK NEW YORK 29875 | 757979 EAST TYRON BLVD NEW YORK NEW YORK |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your text data are examples of this pattern, you can try the following code:

```
df['Address']=df['Text'].str.findall(r'[0-9]{2,6}(.*?)(?:\d+$)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern to extract the values that you want from column Text:

```
\b([0-9]{2,6}\b.*?(?:FLORIDA|NORTH CAROLINA|NEW YORK)) \d
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-9]{2,6}\b` Match 2-6 digits followed by a word boundary
  - `.*?(?:FLORIDA|NORTH CAROLINA|NEW YORK)` Match as least as possible chars until you can match one of the alternatives
- `) \d` Close group 1, and match a space and a digit

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NPmrR9/1).

For example

```
import pandas as pd

items = [
    [1, "UMM SURE THE ADDRESS IS IN 25088 KITTAN DRIVE NORTH CAROLINA 28605"],
    [2, "IT IS ON 26 W STREET 7TH HIGHWAY ORLANDO FLORIDA 28262"],
    [3, "COOL 757979 EAST TYRON BLVD NEW YORK NEW YORK 29875"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["ID", "Text"])
df["Address"] = df["Text"].str.extract(
    r'\b([0-9]{2,6}\b.*?(?:FLORIDA|NORTH CAROLINA|NEW YORK)) \d'
)
print(df)
```

Output

```
   ID                                               Text                                   Address
0   1  UMM SURE THE ADDRESS IS IN 25088 KITTAN DRIVE ...         25088 KITTAN DRIVE NORTH CAROLINA
1   2  IT IS ON 26 W STREET 7TH HIGHWAY ORLANDO FLORI...   26 W STREET 7TH HIGHWAY ORLANDO FLORIDA
2   3  COOL 757979 EAST TYRON BLVD NEW YORK NEW YORK ...  757979 EAST TYRON BLVD NEW YORK NEW YORK
```